# Avoid explicit reloading of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states
  has_one :state, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'State'

  def update_state!(state)
    states.create!(state: state)
  end
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model
end
```

If code is kept like this, then this is the behaviour:

```
m = Model.new(states: State.new(state: 'initial'))
m.save!
m.state.state # => "initial"

m.update_state!("final")
m.state.state # => "initial"
```

One workaround would be changing the `Model#update_state!` to:

```
def update_state!(state)
   states.create!(state: state)
   reload
end
```

Which kind of sucks.

Is there anyway to handle this without having to refresh the record? Something tells me I am missing something...

In this scenario, I might understand that Rails might not know how to relate `:state` with `:states`... However, I even tried making `#state` a plain method instead of an association, but I am still facing the same issue.

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states
  def state
    states.max_by(&:created_at)
  end

  def update_state!(state)
    states.create!(state: state)
  end
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model
end
```

Comment: Have you checked out reset? https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Associations/Association/reset

Answer (score 0):

I would add a foreign key column to models as a "shortcut" to the latest record:

```
class AddStateToModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  change_table :models do |t|
    t.references :state
  end
end
```

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states, 
    after_add: ->(state){ update_columns(state_id: state.id) }
  belongs_to :state, class_name: 'State'

  def update_state!(state)
    states.create!(state: state)
  end
end
```

This is a good read optimization if you are displaying a list of Model instances and there current state as it lets you do a very effective query:

```
@models = Model.eager_load(:current_state)
               .all
```